# Is Linq-to-SQL dying or is it here to stay?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When will linq to sql be phased out? Is entity frameworks (replacement) released yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018928/when-will-linq-to-sql-be-phased-out-is-entity-frameworks-replacement-released)

I remember reading that Linq-to-SQL is going to be phased out i.e. MS isn't going to maintain it much longer.

Is this true? Or is Linq-to-SQL here to stay?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018928/when-will-linq-to-sql-be-phased-out-is-entity-frameworks-replacement-released

Comment: Think it's being replaced by entity framework.

Comment: Actually, I don't see this as a duplicate. The alleged duplicate is from a year and a half ago, which was long before the current .Net framework was released. Times change, and so does Microsoft's strategy. I believe that this is a question worth revisiting from time to time.

Answer (score 3):

Linq to SQL was stopped from being actively developed, because MS has replaced with Entity Frameworks.  That being said, Entity Frameworks incorporates the functionality to Linq To SQL provided.  So to answer your question, yes it is going to be phased out but not really.

Comment: Because of the reverse-compatible nature of .NET, you will likely never see the Linq 2 SQL library disappear from the framework altogether. However, it may become decorated with Obsolete attributes, and the development effort, as Kevin says, is being focused toward EF.

Comment: @Keith no you are absolutely right.  I believe their stance is that it is not going away per se, it just won't be advanced any further.